# How to fix Unity problems after upgrading to Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: unity, compiz, dbus

After upgrading to Ubuntu 14.04, I am having trouble with my display. I tried the following to fix...

```
dconf reset -f /org/compiz/
setsid unity
```

...but on doing the setsid unity, I get the following errors. Kindly advise.

```
rahul@rahul-Latitude-E6430:~$ setsid unity
rahul@rahul-Latitude-E6430:~$ unity-panel-service stop/waiting
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: core
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: core
unity-panel-service start/running, process 3054
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: ccp
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: ccp
compizconfig - Info: Backend     : gsettings
compizconfig - Info: Integration : true
compizconfig - Info: Profile     : unity
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: composite
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: composite
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: opengl
compiz (core) - Info: Unity is fully supported by your hardware.
compiz (core) - Info: Unity is fully supported by your hardware.
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: opengl
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: copytex
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: copytex
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: grid
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: grid
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: imgpng
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: imgpng
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: resize
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: resize
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: place
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: place
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: move
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: move
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: snap
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: snap
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: regex
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: regex
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: mousepoll
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: mousepoll
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: session
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: session
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: commands
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: commands
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: unitymtgrabhandles
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: unitymtgrabhandles
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: wall
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: wall
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: compiztoolbox
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: compiztoolbox
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: vpswitch
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: vpswitch
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: animation
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: animation
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: expo
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: expo
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: ezoom
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: ezoom
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: fade
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: fade
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: workarounds
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: workarounds
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: scale
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: scale
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: unityshell
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: unityshell
WARN  2014-07-10 11:46:38 unity.glib.dbus.server GLibDBusServer.cpp:579 Can't register object 'org.gnome.Shell' yet as we don't have a connection, waiting for it...
ERROR 2014-07-10 11:46:38 unity.debug.interface DebugDBusInterface.cpp:216 Unable to load entry point in libxpathselect: libxpathselect.so.1.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
WARN  2014-07-10 11:46:38 xim.controller XIMController.cpp:103 IBus natively supported.
WARN  2014-07-10 11:46:38 unity.glib.dbus.server GLibDBusServer.cpp:579 Can't register object 'com.canonical.Unity.Launcher' yet as we don't have a connection, waiting for it...
WARN  2014-07-10 11:46:38 unity.glib.dbus.server GLibDBusServer.cpp:579 Can't register object 'com.canonical.Unity.Dash' yet as we don't have a connection, waiting for it...
WARN  2014-07-10 11:46:38 unity.glib.dbus.server GLibDBusServer.cpp:579 Can't register object 'org.gnome.SessionManager.EndSessionDialog' yet as we don't have a connection, waiting for it...
WARN  2014-07-10 11:46:38 unity.glib.dbus.server GLibDBusServer.cpp:579 Can't register object 'com.canonical.Unity.Session' yet as we don't have a connection, waiting for it...
WARN  2014-07-10 11:46:38 unity.glib.dbus.server GLibDBusServer.cpp:579 Can't register object 'org.gnome.ScreenSaver' yet as we don't have a connection, waiting for it...
ERROR 2014-07-10 11:46:38 unity.glib.dbus.server GLibDBusServer.cpp:524 DBus name lost 'org.gnome.Shell'
ERROR 2014-07-10 11:46:38 unity.glib.dbus.server GLibDBusServer.cpp:524 DBus name lost 'com.canonical.Unity'
```

I also tried to reinstall...

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get install --reinstall unity
```

...but no luck.

Also, running the "unity --reset-icons" throws a whole bunch of errors..

```
ERROR 2014-07-10 14:07:50 nux.gltexture.resource.manager GLTextureResourceManager.cpp:54 Invalid target, impossible to generate a new texture. Null Pixbuf
ERROR 2014-07-10 14:07:50 unityding->source != null :0 g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
WARN  2014-07-10 14:07:50 unity.decoration.style DecorationStyle.cpp:443 No Window button file for 'minimize'
ERROR 2014-07-10 14:07:50 unity_is_valid (res, icon) :0 gdk_pixbuf_new_from_file_at_scale: assertion 'width > 0 || width == -1' failed
ERROR 2014-07-10 14:07:50 nux.gltexture.resource.manager GLTextureResourceManager.cpp:54 Invalid target, impossible to generate a new texture. Null Pixbuf
ERROR 2014-07-10 14:07:50 unityding->source != null :0 g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
WARN  2014-07-10 14:07:50 unity.decoration.style DecorationStyle.cpp:443 No Window button file for 'minimize_focused_prelight'
ERROR 2014-07-10 14:07:50 unity_is_valid (res, icon) :0 gdk_pixbuf_new_from_file_at_scale: assertion 'width > 0 || width == -1' failed
ERROR 2014-07-10 14:07:50 nux.gltexture.resource.manager GLTextureResourceManager.cpp:54 Invalid target, impossible to generate a new texture. Null Pixbuf
ERROR 2014-07-10 14:07:50 unityding->source != null :0 g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
WARN  2014-07-10 14:07:50 unity.decoration.style DecorationStyle.cpp:443 No Window button file for 'minimize_focused_pressed'
ERROR 2014-07-10 14:07:50 unity_is_valid (res, icon) :0 gdk_pixbuf_new_from_file_at_scale: assertion 'width > 0 || width == -1' failed
ERROR 2014-07-10 14:07:50 nux.gltexture.resource.manager GLTextureResourceManager.cpp:54 Invalid target, impossible to generate a new texture. Null Pixbuf
ERROR 2014-07-10 14:07:50 unityding->source != null :0 g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
WARN  2014-07-10 14:07:50 unity.decoration.style DecorationStyle.cpp:443 No Window button file for 'minimize_unfocused'
ERROR 2014-07-10 14:07:50 unity_is_valid (res, icon) :0 gdk_pixbuf_new_from_file_at_scale: assertion 'width > 0 || width == -1' failed
ERROR 2014-07-10 14:07:50 nux.gltexture.resource.manager GLTextureResourceManager.cpp:54 Invalid target, impossible to generate a new texture. Null Pixbuf
ERROR 2014-07-10 14:07:50 unityding->source != null :0 g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
WARN  2014-07-10 14:07:50 unity.decoration.style DecorationStyle.cpp:443 No Window button file for 'minimize_unfocused'
ERROR 2014-07-10 14:07:50 unity_is_valid (res, icon) :0 gdk_pixbuf_new_from_file_at_scale: assertion 'width > 0 || width == -1' failed
ERROR 2014-07-10 14:07:50 nux.gltexture.resource.manager GLTextureResourceManager.cpp:54 Invalid target, impossible to generate a new texture. Null Pixbuf
ERROR 2014-07-10 14:07:50 unityding->source != null :0 g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
WARN  2014-07-10 14:07:50 unity.decoration.style DecorationStyle.cpp:443 No Window button file for 'minimize_unfocused_prelight'
ERROR 2014-07-10 14:07:50 unity_is_valid (res, icon) :0 gdk_pixbuf_new_from_file_at_scale: assertion 'width > 0 || width == -1' failed
ERROR 2014-07-10 14:07:50 nux.gltexture.resource.manager GLTextureResourceManager.cpp:54 Invalid target, impossible to generate a new texture. Null Pixbuf
ERROR 2014-07-10 14:07:50 unityding->source != null :0 g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
WARN  2014-07-10 14:07:50 unity.decoration.style DecorationStyle.cpp:443 No Window button file for 'minimize_unfocused_pressed'
ERROR 2014-07-10 14:07:50 unity_is_valid (res, icon) :0 gdk_pixbuf_new_from_file_at_scale: assertion 'width > 0 || width == -1' failed
ERROR 2014-07-10 14:07:50 nux.gltexture.resource.manager GLTextureResourceManager.cpp:54 Invalid target, impossible to generate a new texture. Null Pixbuf
ERROR 2014-07-10 14:07:50 unityding->source != null :0 g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
WARN  2014-07-10 14:07:50 unity.decoration.style DecorationStyle.cpp:443 No Window button file for 'unmaximize'
ERROR 2014-07-10 14:07:50 unity_is_valid (res, icon) :0 gdk_pixbuf_new_from_file_at_scale: assertion 'width > 0 || width == -1' failed
ERROR 2014-07-10 14:07:50 nux.gltexture.resource.manager GLTextureResourceManager.cpp:54 Invalid target, impossible to generate a new texture. Null Pixbuf
ERROR 2014-07-10 14:07:50 unityding->source != null :0 g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
WARN  2014-07-10 14:07:50 unity.decoration.style DecorationStyle.cpp:443 No Window button file for 'unmaximize_focused_prelight'
ERROR 2014-07-10 14:07:50 unity_is_valid (res, icon) :0 gdk_pixbuf_new_from_file_at_scale: assertion 'width > 0 || width == -1' failed
ERROR 2014-07-10 14:07:50 nux.gltexture.resource.manager GLTextureResourceManager.cpp:54 Invalid target, impossible to generate a new texture. Null Pixbuf
ERROR 2014-07-10 14:07:50 unityding->source != null :0 g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
WARN  2014-07-10 14:07:50 unity.decoration.style DecorationStyle.cpp:443 No Window button file for 'unmaximize_focused_pressed'
ERROR 2014-07-10 14:07:50 unity_is_valid (res, icon) :0 gdk_pixbuf_new_from_file_at_scale: assertion 'width > 0 || width == -1' failed
ERROR 2014-07-10 14:07:50 nux.gltexture.resource.manager GLTextureResourceManager.cpp:54 Invalid target, impossible to generate a new texture. Null Pixbuf
ERROR 2014-07-10 14:07:50 unityding->source != null :0 g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
WARN  2014-07-10 14:07:50 unity.decoration.style DecorationStyle.cpp:443 No Window button file for 'unmaximize_unfocused'
ERROR 2014-07-10 14:07:50 unity_is_valid (res, icon) :0 gdk_pixbuf_new_from_file_at_scale: assertion 'width > 0 || width == -1' failed
ERROR 2014-07-10 14:07:50 nux.gltexture.resource.manager GLTextureResourceManager.cpp:54 Invalid target, impossible to generate a new texture. Null Pixbuf
ERROR 2014-07-10 14:07:50 unityding->source != null :0 g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
WARN  2014-07-10 14:07:50 unity.decoration.style DecorationStyle.cpp:443 No Window button file for 'unmaximize_unfocused'
ERROR 2014-07-10 14:07:50 unity_is_valid (res, icon) :0 gdk_pixbuf_new_from_file_at_scale: assertion 'width > 0 || width == -1' failed
ERROR 2014-07-10 14:07:50 nux.gltexture.resource.manager GLTextureResourceManager.cpp:54 Invalid target, impossible to generate a new texture. Null Pixbuf
ERROR 2014-07-10 14:07:50 unityding->source != null :0 g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
WARN  2014-07-10 14:07:50 unity.decoration.style DecorationStyle.cpp:443 No Window button file for 'unmaximize_unfocused_prelight'
ERROR 2014-07-10 14:07:50 unity_is_valid (res, icon) :0 gdk_pixbuf_new_from_file_at_scale: assertion 'width > 0 || width == -1' failed
ERROR 2014-07-10 14:07:50 nux.gltexture.resource.manager GLTextureResourceManager.cpp:54 Invalid target, impossible to generate a new texture. Null Pixbuf
ERROR 2014-07-10 14:07:50 unityding->source != null :0 g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
WARN  2014-07-10 14:07:50 unity.decoration.style DecorationStyle.cpp:443 No Window button file for 'unmaximize_unfocused_pressed'
ERROR 2014-07-10 14:07:50 unity_is_valid (res, icon) :0 gdk_pixbuf_new_from_file_at_scale: assertion 'width > 0 || width == -1' failed
ERROR 2014-07-10 14:07:50 nux.gltexture.resource.manager GLTextureResourceManager.cpp:54 Invalid target, impossible to generate a new texture. Null Pixbuf
ERROR 2014-07-10 14:07:50 unityding->source != null :0 g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
WARN  2014-07-10 14:07:50 unity.decoration.style DecorationStyle.cpp:443 No Window button file for 'maximize'
ERROR 2014-07-10 14:07:50 unity_is_valid (res, icon) :0 gdk_pixbuf_new_from_file_at_scale: assertion 'width > 0 || width == -1' failed
ERROR 2014-07-10 14:07:50 nux.gltexture.resource.manager GLTextureResourceManager.cpp:54 Invalid target, impossible to generate a new texture. Null Pixbuf
ERROR 2014-07-10 14:07:50 unityding->source != null :0 g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
WARN  2014-07-10 14:07:50 unity.decoration.style DecorationStyle.cpp:443 No Window button file for 'maximize_focused_prelight'
ERROR 2014-07-10 14:07:50 unity_is_valid (res, icon) :0 gdk_pixbuf_new_from_file_at_scale: assertion 'width > 0 || width == -1' failed
ERROR 2014-07-10 14:07:50 nux.gltexture.resource.manager GLTextureResourceManager.cpp:54 Invalid target, impossible to generate a new texture. Null Pixbuf
ERROR 2014-07-10 14:07:50 unityding->source != null :0 g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
WARN  2014-07-10 14:07:50 unity.decoration.style DecorationStyle.cpp:443 No Window button file for 'maximize_focused_pressed'
ERROR 2014-07-10 14:07:50 unity_is_valid (res, icon) :0 gdk_pixbuf_new_from_file_at_scale: assertion 'width > 0 || width == -1' failed
ERROR 2014-07-10 14:07:50 nux.gltexture.resource.manager GLTextureResourceManager.cpp:54 Invalid target, impossible to generate a new texture. Null Pixbuf
ERROR 2014-07-10 14:07:50 unityding->source != null :0 g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
WARN  2014-07-10 14:07:50 unity.decoration.style DecorationStyle.cpp:443 No Window button file for 'maximize_unfocused'
ERROR 2014-07-10 14:07:50 unity_is_valid (res, icon) :0 gdk_pixbuf_new_from_file_at_scale: assertion 'width > 0 || width == -1' failed
ERROR 2014-07-10 14:07:50 nux.gltexture.resource.manager GLTextureResourceManager.cpp:54 Invalid target, impossible to generate a new texture. Null Pixbuf
ERROR 2014-07-10 14:07:50 unityding->source != null :0 g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
WARN  2014-07-10 14:07:50 unity.decoration.style DecorationStyle.cpp:443 No Window button file for 'maximize_unfocused'
ERROR 2014-07-10 14:07:50 unity_is_valid (res, icon) :0 gdk_pixbuf_new_from_file_at_scale: assertion 'width > 0 || width == -1' failed
ERROR 2014-07-10 14:07:50 nux.gltexture.resource.manager GLTextureResourceManager.cpp:54 Invalid target, impossible to generate a new texture. Null Pixbuf
ERROR 2014-07-10 14:07:50 unityding->source != null :0 g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
WARN  2014-07-10 14:07:50 unity.decoration.style DecorationStyle.cpp:443 No Window button file for 'maximize_unfocused_prelight'
ERROR 2014-07-10 14:07:50 unity_is_valid (res, icon) :0 gdk_pixbuf_new_from_file_at_scale: assertion 'width > 0 || width == -1' failed
ERROR 2014-07-10 14:07:50 nux.gltexture.resource.manager GLTextureResourceManager.cpp:54 Invalid target, impossible to generate a new texture. Null Pixbuf
ERROR 2014-07-10 14:07:50 unityding->source != null :0 g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
WARN  2014-07-10 14:07:50 unity.decoration.style DecorationStyle.cpp:443 No Window button file for 'maximize_unfocused_pressed'
ERROR 2014-07-10 14:07:50 unity_is_valid (res, icon) :0 gdk_pixbuf_new_from_file_at_scale: assertion 'width > 0 || width == -1' failed
ERROR 2014-07-10 14:07:50 nux.gltexture.resource.manager GLTextureResourceManager.cpp:54 Invalid target, impossible to generate a new texture. Null Pixbuf
ERROR 2014-07-10 14:07:50 unityding->source != null :0 g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
WARN  2014-07-10 14:07:50 unity.decoration.style DecorationStyle.cpp:443 No Window button file for 'close'
```

Any help is appreciated.

```
rahul@rahul-Latitude-E6430:~$ /usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p
OpenGL vendor string:   Intel Open Source Technology Center
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) Ivybridge Mobile x86/MMX/SSE2
OpenGL version string:  3.0 Mesa 10.1.3

Not software rendered:    yes
Not blacklisted:          yes
GLX fbconfig:             yes
GLX texture from pixmap:  yes
GL npot or rect textures: yes
GL vertex program:        yes
GL fragment program:      yes
GL vertex buffer object:  yes
GL framebuffer object:    yes
GL version is 1.4+:       yes

Unity 3D supported:       yes
```

My video card is:

```
lspci -v | less

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09) 
    (prog-if 00 [VGA controller]) Subsystem: Dell Device 0534 Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, 
    IRQ 43 Memory at f6400000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4M] Memory at e0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M] 
    I/O ports at f000 [size=64] Expansion ROM at <unassigned> [disabled] 
    Capabilities: <access denied> Kernel driver in use: i915
```

Comment: What video card do you have?

Comment: lspci -v | less  
    00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Dell Device 0534
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 43
    Memory at f6400000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4M]
    Memory at e0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    I/O ports at f000 [size=64]
    Expansion ROM at <unassigned> [disabled]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: i915

Comment: I have this problem after upgrading from 14.04 to 14.10 with same video card